# why django page not found/ URL patterns didn't match?

Tags: python, django, url, django-views, django-templates

**why page not found what is incrorrect on my code ?**

and there the dealerships code if there any mistake let me know

**dealships-home-**

```
` <body>  
   <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">  
     <div class="container-fluid">   
      <div class="navbar-header">       
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dealership Review</a>   
      </div>         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">    
       {% if user.is_authenticated %}         
  <div class="rightalign">          
   <div class="dropdown"> 
              <button class="dropbtn">{{user.first_name}}</button>     
          <div class="dropdown-content">    
             <a href="{% url 'djangoapp:logout' %}">Logout</a>  
             </div>          
   </div>       
    </div>  
         {% else %}     
      <div class="rightalign">  
           <div class="dropdown">       
        <form action="{% url 'djangoapp:registration' %}" method="get">  
               <input class="dropbtn" type="submit" value="Visitor" />    
             <div class="dropdown-content">        
           <a href="{% url 'djangoapp:registration' %}">Signup</a>   
                <a href="{% url 'djangoapp:login' %}">Login</a>   
              </div>     
          </form>   
          </div>      
     </div>         
  {% endif %}  
       </ul>    
   </div>   
  </nav>`
```

and there the url code if there any mistake let me know
**url:**

```
`app_name = 'djangoapp'
urlpatterns = [

# path for dealerships/index
path(route='dealerships/', view=views.get_dealerships, name='dealerships'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
`
```

and there the views code if there any mistake let me know
**Views:**

```
`
def get_dealerships(request):
context = {}
if request.method == "GET":
return render(request, 'djangoapp/dealerships.html', context)`
```

**Any suggestions**
the code not working and it give me page not found
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1VCf.png)

Comment: Provide a detailed error/stack trace describtion.